# SSRS masking the mail id and mobile number column

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-expression

In my ssrs report I want to mask the `mail_id` and `Mobile_number` column

The format I required in my report like below:

For mobile number:

First two digits  + *(5 times) + last 3 digits

For Email ID:

First two characters  + *(5 times) + domain name after "@"

[image]

Modification in procedure is strictly prohibited.

Answer (score 1):

Try this for `Mobile_number`:

```
=Left(Fields!Mobile_number.Value,2) & StrDup(5,"*") & RIGHT(Fields!Mobile_number.Value,3)
```

This for `mail_id`:

```
=Replace(
  Fields!email_id.Value,
  Mid(Fields!email_id.Value,3,Instr(Fields!email_id.Value,"@")-3),
  StrDup(LEN(Mid(Fields!email_id.Value,3,Instr(Fields!email_id.Value,"@")-3)),"*"))
```

If you want to fix the number of `*` to five for `email_id`, simply use:

```
=LEFT(Fields!email_id.Value,2) &
StrDup(5,"*") &
Right(
      Fields!email_id.Value,
      LEN(Fields!email_id.Value)-
      InStr(Fields!email_id.Value,"@")+1
)
```

Let me know if this helps.